# Am I charged for AWS Application Load Balancer if it's not handling any requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am considering using AWS Application Load Balancer, but the pricing description says:

> You are charged for each hour or partial hour that an Application Load
> Balancer is running, and the number of Load Balancer Capacity Units
> (LCU) used per hour.

Does this mean if the load balancer is idle and not serving any requests, it is still charging me per hour? I'm concerned I will be paying for it even when it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

As per the [Application and Network Traffic Distribution - Elastic Load Balancing Pricing - AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/) page:

> For Application Load Balancers in the AWS Region:
>
> $0.0225 per Application Load Balancer-hour (or partial hour)
> $0.008 per LCU-hour (or partial hour)

Thus, even if it is not handling any traffic, you will be charged **$0.0225 per Application Load Balancer-hour (or partial hour)**.

(Pricing might vary by Region.)